# Android AutoFitTextureView not working

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to use AutoFitTextureView in one project. I have declared:

```
private AutoFitTextureView mCameraLayout;
```

But it is showing in red that it cannot be resolved. I wanted to know which packages need to be imported and how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That class is a custom class which is not included in Android SDK. You may see the source [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/src/com.example.android.camera2basic/AutoFitTextureView.html).

Comment: How can I use it. is there an alternative or anyway to integrate it. Thanks.

Comment: Copy paste it to your project.